# Jooq (java) - Type class org.jooq.impl.UnqualifiedName is not supported in dialect DEFAULT

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Hello I am doing this in method

```
public void update(Table table, String tableName){
    ArrayList<Name> firstRowInDslFormat = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object value : table.getTableDataInRowFormat(false).get(0))
        firstRowInDslFormat.add(DSL.name(value.toString()));

    for (int rowId = 1; rowId < table.getTableDataInRowFormat(false).size(); rowId++) {
        stringBuilder.append("\n" + ctx
             .update(DSL.table(DSL.name(tableName)))
             .set(
                 DSL.row(firstRowInDslFormat), 
                 DSL.row(table.getTableDataInRowFormat(false).get(rowId))
             )
             .where(...).getSQL(ParamType.INLINED) + ";");
    }  
}
```

> getTableDataInRowFormat() returns Map(Integer,ArrayList) -> Map(rowId,
>   row column values in string)

I don't know how to fix it. I tried to as you see at start method to change type from String to Name, but it throws me error:
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class org.jooq.impl.UnqualifiedName is not supported in dialect DEFAULT

When I am using just strings like this:

```
 DSL.row(table.getTableDataInRowFormat(false).get(0)), 
 DSL.row(table.getTableDataInRowFormat(false).get(rowId))).where()...
```

it works... but it returns me column name with ' ' as you see in output below ... and when I run this it will throws error because of syntax, where ' ' are not expected.

> Output when I use only strings:
>
> 1. update New_tab1 set 'id' = '0', 'name' = 'John' where (id=1);
> 2. update New_tab1 set 'id' = '1', 'name' = 'Pierce' where (id=2);

I know this topics are already created but it is little bit different, I think.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a limitation in the jOOQ API. You should be able to pass a set of [`org.jooq.Name`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Name.html) instances (or [`org.jooq.Select`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Select.html) instances) to [`DSL.row(Collection<?>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row-java.util.Collection-). I've created an issue for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8492

As a workaround, please use `Field<?>` instances, instead of `Name` instances:

```
ArrayList<Field<?>> firstRowInDslFormat = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object value : table.getTableDataInRowFormat(false).get(0))
    firstRowInDslFormat.add(DSL.field(DSL.name(value.toString()), value.getClass()));
```